# React Formik get form state's values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form with two fields name and age. I know when user fill these two fields and hit the submit button I can get the values for these two fields.

But what I want is, I have a button call **show filled values**. When your press that button I want to see the user-filled values in the form. For example, if he fills name as 'Tom' and age as 85. I want to see that. But right now what I am getting is the empty initial values object.

[My Code](http://show%20filled%20values)

How do I achieve this using Reactjs?

Comment: I think your link is broken

Comment: after submit you can store the values to some state and that can use wherever you want, hence your link is broken we can't able to find exact issue

Comment: How is that an almost 4k user posts code in a link rather than in the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

U can get the filled fields using Formiks props provided by the **Formik**.

The **values**  prop provided by the formik will gives the filled fields values. Initially it will be the empty object . After you start filling the fields, the **values** object will be updated accordingly.

To know more What Props can **Formik** provide ?

visit :-  https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#touched--field-string-boolean-

Hope the below code snippet will be useful for you.

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{}}
        validationSchema={() => Yup.object().shape({`enter your validation keys here`})}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log('values after submit', values);
        }}
      >
        {(formikProps) => {
          const { values, handleChange } = formikProps;
          return (
            <Form>
              <label>
                name
                <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
              </label>
              <label>
                age
                <input name="age" type="number" onChange={handleChange} />
              </label>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log('show filled fields', values);
                }}
              >
                Show Filled Fields
              </button>
              <button type={'submit'}> Submit</button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer here! Might I suggest that you add some details about what you fixed or why it is right? It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Consider this is a rule for all your answers on Stackoverflow.